# FluentValidation duplication of concatenation of strings

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I am new to FluentValidation. I am looking for duplication validation. I have a collection of 2 strings. It has to be concatenated and checked for duplication.

```
public class RecordValidator : AbstractValidator<RecordRow>
{
   public RecordValidator()
    {
       RuleFor(x => x.Name)
      .Must(x => concatnatedvalue.Contains(x))
      .WithMessage("Not a unique value");                   
       
    }

   //concatenate the string
   private bool concatnatedvalue(RecordRow rr)
   {      
     //Check for validation for concatenated string of Name && surname
      var result = rr.Name && rr.Surname
      return result;
   }
 }
```

Comment: What is the question? The example code probably doesn't compie, does it? You cannot use a function like that. What types are `Name` and `SurName`? I also do not understand where you expect this to detect duplication?

Comment: Why just not check for Name != Surname?